# Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError (can't convert Symbol into Integer)

Tags: chef-infra, erb, chef-template

I'm trying to use the below set attribute values from attribute file to comapany_name.properties.erb file.

But the values are not passed.

webapp/attributes/default.rb file

```
default['webapp']['company_name']['task_server'] = "false"
default['webapp']['company_name']['task_url'] = "localhost:8080"
default['webapp']['company_name']['task_queue'] = "simple"
```

webapp/templates/default/company_name.properties.erb file

```
# Tasks
task.server= <%=node [:webapp][:company_name1][:task_server]%>
task.url= <%=node [:webapp][:company_name1][:task_url]%>
task.queue.type= <%= node [:webapp][:company_name1][:task_queue]%>
```

Executing chef-client, the following error is seen:

```
Running handlers:
[2015-01-22T05:31:51+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2015-01-22T05:31:51+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2015-01-22T05:31:51+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 8 resources updated in 9.220599177 seconds
[2015-01-22T05:31:51+00:00] ERROR: 

  Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError (can't convert Symbol into Integer) on line #20:

 18: 
 19: # Tasks
 20: task.server= <%= node [:webapp][:company_name1][:task_server]%>
 21: task.url= <%= node [:webapp][:company_name1][:task_url]%>
 22: task.queue.type=  <%= node [:webapp][:company_name1][:task_queue]%>

  (erubis):21:in `[]'
  (erubis):21:in `block in evaluate'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/erubis-2.7.0/lib/erubis/evaluator.rb:74:in `instance_eval'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/erubis-2.7.0/lib/erubis/evaluator.rb:74:in `evaluate'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/mixin/template.rb:126:in `_render_template'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/mixin/template.rb:112:in `render_template'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/provider/template/content.rb:43:in `file_for_provider'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/file_content_management/content_base.rb:40:in `tempfile'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:411:in `tempfile'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:350:in `do_contents_changes'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:121:in `action_create'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:131:in `action_create_if_missing'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/provider.rb:121:in `run_action'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/resource.rb:648:in `run_action'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/runner.rb:49:in `run_action'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `each'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block in converge'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:98:in `block in execute_each_resource'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:96:in `execute_each_resource'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/runner.rb:80:in `converge'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/client.rb:345:in `converge'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/client.rb:431:in `do_run'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/client.rb:213:in `block in run'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/client.rb:207:in `fork'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/client.rb:207:in `run'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/application.rb:236:in `run_chef_client'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:338:in `block in run_application'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:327:in `loop'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:327:in `run_application'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/application.rb:55:in `run'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
  /bin/chef-client:23:in `load'
  /bin/chef-client:23:in `<main>'


[2015-01-22T05:31:51+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a space between `node` and the `[]` call. That should be `node[:webapp][:company_name1][:task_server]`,

Comment: You also seem to be mixing `company` and `company1`.